# Chrome DevTools - Network - Remove overview time filter

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Once you click, and thereby filter, on the network timeline overview, I cannot find a way to undo the filtering.

[image]

When double clicking, it increases the filter to all, but subsequent requests won't be shown, as the filter is not removed, it is just moved to the newest time at the moment of double clicking.

[image]
[image]

Closing and opening the DevTools, or clearing the network tab, are the only ways I found so far (apart from increasing the filter everytime I need to see the newest requests), but keeping the request log without any timeline filtering is the goal.

Comment: Ha, that's annoying. Took me a few minutes to replicate, and I also can't figure out how to remove that time-based filter.

Comment: This is one of the dumbest UI decisions I've ever seen in my life. They made the ability to create a filter but not the ability to REMOVE it??

Comment: this has been bugging me (and collegues) off for years, i can't believe there is no popup, no shortcut, now way to resolve this except closing and reopening the console, apart maybe from cleaning all the data

Comment: Incredibly annoying when you're halfway through debugging and you don't want to refresh the page and loose all the local data.

Answer (score -3):

Drag the limits to the very edge of the graph and release.

Comment: Draggin the limit to the edge is the same as double clicking, or using the scroll wheel to increase the range to the maximun. The problem remains, new requests fall outside the "range" and you have to drag/double click/scroll again to see new requests.